# Get Progress Events of Cordova File Transfer from factory with Ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have this factory that manages the upload file with Cordova File Transfer plugin:

```
app.factory('Camera', function($q) {

var url = "http://www.myurl.com";

return {
   uploadPicture: function (imgURI, fileName) {
        var q = $q.defer();

        function win(r) {
            q.resolve(r.response);
        }

        function fail(e) {
            q.reject(e);
        }

        var options = {
            fileKey: "file",
            fileName: fileName,
            chunkedMode: false,
            mimeType: "image/jpg"
        };

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imgURI, url, win, fail, options);
        return q.promise;
    }
  }
});
```

From my controller I use it like this:

```
 Camera.uploadPicture(imagePath, fileName).then(function (res) {
           //Some code

        }), function (err) {
           //Some code
        }
```

I would like to get back the onprogress event from factory to display the progress of upload in the view. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function to do your $cordovaFileTransfer function

```
function (progressEvent) {
    var perc = Math.floor(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total * 100);

    if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {                      
        $ionicLoading.show({
             template: 'uploading... '+perc
        });

    } else {
        loadingStatus.increment();
    }

});
```